# global variable from main.c is undeclared in header file function

Tags: c

the main.c contains a global variable called `cell2VoltageUV` which is given a value by function: 
`updateMeasurements();`
this function is also located inside the main.c but not in the main function.

whenever I try to print the `cell2VoltageUV` using a function in another .c file which also has a .h header file, I get the error:

> 'cell2VoltageUV' undeclared (first use in this function)

if i just do `printf(cell2VoltageUV);` in the main function i get the correct value but if the same `printf(cell2VoltageUV);` is located in another .c file function i get the error.

how do I get the correct value inside of the function I'm making?

ps. this is my first post here and I'm relatively new to c programming (Arduino experience only), this project I'm working on already has a lot of functions built-in and I'm trying to add more features.

Comment: Please post a [mcve], don't just describe your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lets say that your variable is of type int;

```
int cell2VoltageU;
```

Then in any other file you use this variable you must have

```
extern int cell2VoltageU;
```